# MVC3 Offline For Update Implementation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I will appreciate any help on steps for an  implementation to switch an  MVC3/Razor Web Application to offline mode for maintenance. At the offline mode only a static page could be seen by the public but an administrator who is logged in should be able to view, browse and update the site fully. Ideally I want the web administrator just to tick on a value at the administrative back-end which will be registered in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply check some condition within BeginRequest in Global.asax.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (myDb.SiteIsOffline && !CurrentUserIsAdministrator())
        Response.Redirect("~/offline.html");
}
```

Comment: Thanks @kgulsang.  I think your solution will be easier  to implement where the administrator will be different from the developer and so I  will implement your solution.